# Change Div height according windows inner height

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic, height, inline

I need a little help here.

I want to change the height of div according to the screen inner height
for which i have written a java script which is as follows

```
<script>
function height()
{
var h = window.innerHeight;

document.getElementById("bg").style.height = h; 
}
</script>
```

Whenever i use

```
document.getElementById("bg").style.height = h;
```

i doesn't write anything to the div element #bg
but when i define a height in px like 500px i does write height in div element #bg.

Comment: You need to use the function as a handler for the [onresize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize) event.

Comment: have you tried `document.getElementById("bg").style.height = h + 'px';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add 'px' to the height value:

```
function height()
{
var h = window.innerHeight;

document.getElementById("bg").style.height = h+'px'; 
}
```

And obviously call the function at some point

```
height();
```

Check out the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/MRttV/

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure css to do this I guess. by defining:

```
   body,
     html {
     height: 100%;
   }
   #bg {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%; /* or the value you want if element is empty */
   }
```

Or you can also use the "vh" value. [But it doesn't work on old browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)